# regex replace special string

Tags: regex

here is a url : http://192.168.84.98/scms?F=image&FORMAT=PNG32&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=show:13&BBOXSR=aaa&IMAGESR=3857&SIZE=2528,867&BBOX=-104100.7571006687,-8544.352197105065,230333.2451006686,106152.75219710357&DPI=90

how to write a javascript regex to replace the string between "&BBOXSR=" and "&"(aaa) to another string like "bbb". note the searching string("aaa") is mutative.

the hope result url string is :http://192.168.84.98/scms?F=image&FORMAT=PNG32&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=show:13&BBOXSR=bbb&IMAGESR=3857&SIZE=2528,867&BBOX=-104100.7571006687,-8544.352197105065,230333.2451006686,106152.75219710357&DPI=90

Comment: Split your URL on `&`  to get all parameters can be a good start. But actually your question is too broad. What language are you using? What is the finally?

Comment: Another case when `regex` is not needed. The job can be done using simple string processing (`split()`, `substr()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that you don't need regex for this task, here you are the solution just for sake of REGEX exercise.

```
var string = " http://192.168.84.98/scms?F=image&FORMAT=PNG32&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=show:13&BBOXSR=aaa&IMAGESR=3857&SIZE=2528,867&BBOX=-104100.7571006687,-8544.352197105065,230333.2451006686,106152.75219710357&DPI=90";

string = string.replace(/(BBOXSR=)(\w)+(?=&)/g, "$1red");
console.info(string)
```